# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

`String query = "INSERT INTO`users`(`int`,`fname`,`lname`,`age`,`sname`,`bname`) VALUES ('"+jTextField_FirstName.getText()+"','"+jTextField_LastName.getText()+"',"+jTextField_Age.getText()+",'"+jTextField_SName.getText()+"','"+jTextField_BName.getText()+"')";`

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 at     
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965) at 
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976) at    
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912) at     
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530) at 
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683) at  
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2482) at 
com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1552)
```

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2482)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1552)

Comment: this really shouldn't have been upvoted in the first place. Code dumps with no explanation of your goal and without formatting are poor quality.

Comment: in case if the first column `int` is of `auto_increment`, then you need not include in `insert` statement. remove it from the column names list in the statement and then execute it.

Comment: Apart from having specified 6 columns and only 5 values, your code is highly unsafe as it is vulnerable to SQL injection. You really should not concatenate values into a query string. Use prepared statements with parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You want to set 6 columns `int, fname, lname, age, sname, bname`

But you're providing 5 column values only.

Add one more column value, then it's OK

Answer (score 0):

```
   String query = "INSERT INTO users(int, fname, lname, age, sname, bname) VALUES   
 ('"+jTextField_FirstName.getText()+"','"+jTextField_LastName.getText()+"',"
        +jTextField_Age.getText()+",'"+jTextField_SName.getText()+"','"
   +jTextField_BName.getText()+"')";
```

According to query you are inserting value for fname,lname,age,sname,bname,
not for int your query shoud like below to set first value for int

```
String query = "INSERT INTO users(int, fname, lname, age, sname, bname) VALUES   


('"+value_for_int+"','"+jTextField_FirstName.getText()+"','"+jTextField_LastName.getText()+"',"
        +jTextField_Age.getText()+",'"+jTextField_SName.getText()+"','"
   +jTextField_BName.getText()+"')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are providing **six** columns as follows:

```
INSERT INTO users (int, fname, lname, age, sname, bname)
```

But has provided only **five** values as follows:

```
jTextField_FirstName.getText()
jTextField_LastName.getText()
jTextField_Age.getText()
jTextField_SName.getText()
jTextField_BName.getText()
```

So provide **one** more value to **int** specified in the **insert query** and then you get no errors...